# Displaying and Removing BufferedImages from JFrame (Whack-A-Mole)

Tags: java

MAJOR EDIT: I have tried a different approach with 1 class and implementation of Runnable to try and print the "moles". I no longer have a second class. The new issue is making the `BufferedImage userInterface` print at the desired coordinates, then printing "moles" randomly at the correct coordinates. The mole should disappear when the next mole is drawn.

Current Problems:

1. If the `userInterface` is alone (no for-loop that is seen below it in the code) then it will appear. If I change the coordinates from 0,0 then it no longer appears.
2. When I added the for-loop that prints the "moles" (a.k.a mario, hence Whack-A-Mario) then the `userInterface` ceases to appear at all even if its coords are still 0,0 AND the moles get printed at the random coordinates. The problem here is that the UI no longer appears and the marios keep being printed without the previous ones disappearing.

---

I am programming a Whack-A-Mole game for my computer programming class, however, I have been having quite a bit of trouble making the images of "moles" appear and disappear.

First, I do not want to use any sort of JButton system for the moles. I have seen it used but I want to use my .png's if possible.

Second, I have concluded that I do not know what I am doing. A major problem is that I also do not really know how to organize the program. The moles will be appearing at a slowly increasing rate and the character will be clicking on the screen. If the user's mouse click is within the area of one of the moles when they are up, the user's score will increase. I have no idea if I should one class or two classes (I have seen people do it in one). I don't exactly know what I am going to do about the updating score either. I want the score to update independently from the repainting of the moles too.

Note: The `BufferedImage mario` is called mario because I am making "Wack-A-Mario". The moles are images of Mario I drew and the music/effects will all be from Mario. Also please excuse my horrid imports. They have increased over the past couple hours as I tried various things. I no longer know what does what and they will be cleaned up.

---

Main Class:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.Timer;
public class WhackAMario extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    int xCoord[] = new int[] {25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609};
    int yCoord[] = new int[] {275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 395, 395, 395, 395, 395, 515, 515, 515, 515, 515, 635, 635, 635, 635, 635,};
    Random coordGen = new Random();
    int x,y,element;

    BufferedImage userInterface, mario;
    private Thread thread;
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static Graphics g;
    private static Graphics2D g2;
    public void randomCoord()
    {
        element = coordGen.nextInt(20);
        x = xCoord[element];
        y = yCoord[element];
    }

    public void run()
    {
        g = frame.getGraphics();
        try
        {
            userInterface = ImageIO.read(new File("UserInterface.png"));            
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.drawImage(userInterface, 0, 0, null);
        for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        {
            randomCoord();
            try
            {
                mario = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario Up.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g.drawImage(mario, x, y, null);
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                repaint();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final WhackComponent whackComponent = new WhackComponent();
        class Mouse implements MouseListener
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
            {

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(796, 818);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        WhackAMario whack = new WhackAMario();
        whack.thread = new Thread(whack);
        whack.thread.start();

        MouseListener listener = new Mouse();
        frame.addMouseListener(listener);


        //Timer t = new Timer(100, whackComponent); 
        //t.start();

        //     
        //         ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Hole.png");
        //         JLabel label1 = new JLabel(img);
        //         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //         panel.setLayout(null);
        //     
        //         label1.setLocation(400, 400);

        //frame.add(label1);
        //frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Main Class Before "MAJOR EDIT"

```
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.Timer;
public class WhackAMario extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    int xCoord[] = new int[] {25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609};
    int yCoord[] = new int[] {275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 395, 395, 395, 395, 395, 515, 515, 515, 515, 515, 635, 635, 635, 635, 635,};
    Random coordGen = new Random();
    int x,y,element;

    BufferedImage userInterface, mario;
    private Thread thread;
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private static Graphics g;
    private static Graphics2D g2;
    public void randomCoord()
    {
        element = coordGen.nextInt(20);
        x = xCoord[element];
        y = yCoord[element];
    }

    public void run()
    {
        g = frame.getGraphics();

        //         try
        //         {
        //             userInterface = ImageIO.read(new File("UserInterface.png"));            
        //         }
        //         catch(IOException e)
        //         {    
        //             e.printStackTrace();
        //         }       
        //         g.drawImage(userInterface, 0, 50, null);

        //         for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        //         {
        //             randomCoord();
        //             try
        //             {
        //                 mario = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario Up.png"));
        //             }
        //             catch(IOException e)
        //             {    
        //                 e.printStackTrace();
        //             }
        //             g.drawImage(mario, x, y, null);
        //             try 
        //             {
        //                 Thread.sleep(1000);
        //                 repaint();
        //             } 
        //             catch (InterruptedException e) 
        //             {
        //                 e.printStackTrace();
        //             }
        //         }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final WhackComponent whackComponent = new WhackComponent();
        class Mouse implements MouseListener
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
            {

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(796, 818);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(whackComponent);

        //         WhackAMario whack = new WhackAMario();
        //         whack.thread = new Thread(whack);
        //         whack.thread.start();

        MouseListener listener = new Mouse();
        frame.addMouseListener(listener);



        //Timer t = new Timer(100, whackComponent); 
        //t.start();

        //     
        //         ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("Hole.png");
        //         JLabel label1 = new JLabel(img);
        //         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //         panel.setLayout(null);
        //     
        //         label1.setLocation(400, 400);

        //frame.add(label1);
        //frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Component Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WhackComponent extends JComponent
{    
    int xCoord[] = new int[] {25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609, 25, 171, 317, 463, 609};
    int yCoord[] = new int[] {275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 395, 395, 395, 395, 395, 515, 515, 515, 515, 515, 635, 635, 635, 635, 635,};
    BufferedImage userInterface, mario;
    Random coordGen = new Random();
    Thread thread;
    int element;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {      
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        try
        {
            userInterface = ImageIO.read(new File("UserInterface.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g2.drawImage(userInterface, null, 0, 0);

        for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
        {

            element = coordGen.nextInt(20);
            try
            {
                mario = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario Up.png"));
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            g2.drawImage(mario, null, xCoord[element], yCoord[element]);
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void enterMove()
    {
    } 

    public void releaseMove() 
    {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to work this way: you provide the drawing logic inside `paintComponent(Graphics)` and the system will call you back when it detects the screen needs to be refreshed. In Swing applications the trigger is tipically the user interacting with the computer, for example by pressing a key or clicking the mouse, while in your application you need a game engine with its own main loop, that shows/hides moles, interacts with the music engine and processes input events depending on the state of the world. In Swing, layout hierarchies are invalidated with a call to `.invalidate()`.

Note that `JButton`'s and others Swing components are just a convenient way for you to draw things (especially wrt screen size with the help of layout managers) and process events, but you can certainly program a simple game by using a single JComponent like in your example (I think [this](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=fvenfkdj0rpu9dcui2v3tmura0&/topic,21919.0.html) may help)

Random tip: `paintComponent` must be fast, and I mean **really fast**, so you can't read a PNG from the filesystem and convert it to a bitmap. The loading must occur exactly one time when the game is initialized

Comment: So if paintComponent needs to happen really fast and occur one time when the game is initialized, I cant go with for-loop containing the Thread.sleep I was using. Would calling paintComponent again and again with a delay from the main class work? If so what is the best method to delay repainting.

Comment: No, paintComponent() is supposed to be called continuously. Only the loading of the bitmap must happen once at game initialization